# Player teleports back and forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When A player goes off screen I would like them to teleport to the other side of the screen, but this isn't working very well.

I have the following script attached to both of the teleport items, but when the player enters the collider it starts teleporting back and forth between the two (both colliders have the following script and a 2d box collider as a trigger).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WallTransport : MonoBehaviour {

    public Collider2D destination;
    public LayerMask layer;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(((1 << other.gameObject.layer) & layer) != 0) {
            Vector2 destPos = destination.transform.position;
            other.transform.position = new Vector2(destPos.x, other.transform.position.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to vary the `position` slightly so that the player is not colliding with the destination teleporter after it teleports.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WallTransport : MonoBehaviour {

    public Collider2D destination;
    public LayerMask layer;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(((1 << other.gameObject.layer) & layer) != 0) {
            Vector2 destPos = destination.transform.position;
            other.transform.position = new Vector2(destPos.x + 1, other.transform.position.y);
            //                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
    }
}
```

For example, in the below image, teleporter B is located at (10,0) and teleporter A is located at (0,0). Rather than spit the player out at (0,0) after they teleport, put them at (1,0), assuming that they entered teleporter B from left to right, so their momentum would continue in that direction.

This is just a simple example, and by no means assumes that your situation is this basic.

[image: simple teleporter example]

Answer (score 0):

Add a bool called something like "has_teleported" and set it to false by default...
Switch this on (true) when you enter a teleport collider, switch it off (false) when you exit a teleport collider.

Only allow the teleport function to work if it is switched off.

The answer by Dub stylee will work and is more simple, however, this way is more dynamic (as teleportation can be enabled and disabled through events etc.) and  scalable if sizes ever need to be changed.

Choose the way that works best for your specific project, there will always be trade-off's.

Hope this helps :)